# Hive / DynamoDB error "Could not find column mapping for column"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata, amazon-dynamodb

I am running the following Hive query on an Amazon Elastic MapReduce EC2 instance:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myExport (access_key string, active bigint,
    api_id string, secret_key string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Authentication",
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "access_key:access_key, active:active, api_id:api_id, secret_key:secret_key");
```

I am trying to grab the contents of the `Authentication` DynamoDB table, but instead I am seeing the following error:

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Could not find column mapping for column: active)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out Hive doesn't trim the DynamoDB column mappings after splitting on the commas, so the list of column mappings must not contain spaces.

The fix: changing the comma-plus-space (", ") separated list:

```
"dynamodb.column.mapping"
    = "access_key:access_key, active:active, api_id:api_id, secret_key:secret_key"
```

Into a comma-only (",") separated list:

```
"dynamodb.column.mapping"
    = "access_key:access_key,active:active,api_id:api_id,secret_key:secret_key"
```

And now it works.

Comment: Unbelievable! You saved me hours for sure